# How to create a random number using the current time

Tags: c, random

I have 4 bytes of space to create a random number. The Last byte is used for container and slot (Not relevant to this question) so I have 3 bytes to fill the current time (epoch also will do)

I have the following so far:

```
uint32_t create_handle(uint8_t container_id, uint8_t file_slot)
{
    uint32_t handle;

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    handle = ((now << 24) & ~(0xFF));
    handle += (container_id << 4) + file_slot; /* Last byte is 4 bits of container + 4 bits of slot */
    return handle;
}
```

Is this correct? I am able to generate random number but I am unable to assess if it going to valid. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: why don't you use `rand()`? Time is far from being random.

Comment: shift left always fills 0 in, no need for `& ~(0xFF)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shifting now by 24, which only leaves 8.  I think you want to just shift by 8.  The `& ~(0xff)` is redundant.

How about using one of the random number libraries?  or are you never going to need more than one handle per second?

Comment: Yes, I am not going to need one for more than a second. The requirement is that I use current time

Answer (score 1):

`srand (time(NULL))` to provide randomization seed. `rand ()` to get random number.